# I wonder if $K$ is a field then $K[X]$ is a PID then the ideals of it have formula that is $<f(X)>$ when $f(X)$ is a polynomial with coefficent in $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

I see the solution of proving if K is a field then $K[X]$ is PID that is taking the minimal polynomial of ideal but I do not see they use the hypothesis K is field? Especially, I do not see the difference between K is ring and K is field.
Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: In what you write about maximal ideals, probably it has $K = \mathbb{Z}$ rather than a field (otherwise the term "prime number" would usually not be used).

Comment: Let me try to extract the precise question from your confusing text: You want to know how the proof, that any ideal of $K[X]$ is principal, fails for $\mathbb Z[X]$?

Comment: I am sorry I will edit my post.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Answer (score 2):

The proof that $K[X]$ is a PID uses essentially that we can do polynomial division in $K[X]$.

In $\mathbb Z[X]$ however we cannot perform polynomial division, i.e. for $a=X$ and $b=2$ there are no $q,r$ with $\deg r < \deg a$ and $a=qb+r$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it

Answer (score 0):

the difference  that is if  $K[X]$ is  a principal domain then
$\forall a\in K^*$ the ideal $(a) + (X)$ is principal, so there i
s $P\in K[X]$ such that $(a) + (X) = (P)$, this applique that $a$
and $X$  are in $(P)$, and so $a = PQ$ and $X = PR$   for some $Q,R\in
K[X]$ , since  $K[X]$ is one integral domain we have  $dega = degP +
degG $, and this shows that $P$ is a constant $b\in K$, so $X = b R $ and so
as $  degX=1$  therefore necessarily $R = c X$ with $c$ a constant
in $K$; the equality $ X =  bcX $  shows that $bc = 1$ and so $b$
invertible and therefor  $(a) + (X) = (1)=K[X]$; by Bézout's
theorem there is $  M,N \in K[X]$ such that $aM + NX = 1$ this is
true only if $N = 0$ (definition of polynomial) and $M$ is a constant
$m\in K$ ; so then $am = 1$ and $a$ reversible in $K$ and so
$K$ a field.